# GreenDao: queryBuilder not a method on an entity dao

Tags: android, orm, greendao

I've been attempting to get acquainted with the `GreenDao` Android ORM library. I've been following along with Green Robot's examples but have gotten stuck. Whenever I get an instance of one of my daos, `UserDao`, I don't have any sort of `queryBuilder()` method associated with the dao object.

```
import package.DaoMaster;
import package.DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper;
import package.DaoSession;
import package.UserDao;

public class DatabaseHelper {

    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private DaoMaster daoMaster;
    private DaoSession daoSession;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        DevOpenHelper helper = new DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper(context, "db", null);

        this.db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        this.daoMaster = new DaoMaster(db);
        this.daoSession = this.daoMaster.newSession();

        // attempting to retrieve the queryBuilder instance from a user dao....
        // however, no queryBuilder method exists
        this.daoSession.getUserDao().queryBuilder();
    }
}
```

What am I missing guys? I'm using the `greendao-generator` artifact, versioned at `1.3.1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured this out. First, I'm using `Android Studio 0.8.9`, which is using `Gradle 2.1`.

In the `build.gradle` file in the project's `app` folder, I added `compile( 'de.greenrobot:greendao:1.3.7')` to its `dependencies` section. It looks something like this:

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    compile 'de.greenrobot:greendao:1.3.7'
    // ...
}
```

From then on, the `queryBuilder` method was available for all my `daos`.